# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'qn' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, stringio

I'm getting the error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'qn' referenced before assignment" on running the code. Why is that? How can I correct it? I'm new to tkinter so please try to keep it simple. This is part of the code for a game I was writing. It would be a great help if I could get an answer soon

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import messagebox 
from io import StringIO

root = Tk() 
root.title("Captain!") 
root.geometry("660x560")                                   

qn = '''1$who are you?$char1$i am joe$3$i am ben$2
2$what are you?$char2$i am a person$1$i am nobody$3
3$how are you?$char3$i am fine$2$i'm alright$1'''
var = '''1$10$-35$20$15$-20
2$9$7$30$-5$-15
3$10$-25$-15$10$5'''

class Game :
    def __init__(self): 
        self.m_cur = {1:["Military",50]}
        self.c_cur = {1:["People's",50]}
        self.r_cur = {1:["Research",50]}
        self.i_cur = {1:["Industrial",50]}
        self.p_cur = {1:["Research",50]}

    #function to clear all widgets on screen when called
    def clear(self):
        for widget in root.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
    
    #function to quit the window
    def exit(self):
        msg = messagebox.askquestion("Thank you for playing","Are you sure you want to exit?")
        if msg == "yes" :
            root.destroy()
        else:
            Game.main(self)

    #start function
    def start(self):
        Label(root,text="Hello, what should we call you?",font=("segoe print",20)).grid(row=0,column=0)
        name = Entry(root,width=20)
        name.grid(row=1,column=0)
        Button(root,text="Enter",font=("segoe print",20),command=lambda: Game.main(self)).grid(row=1,column=1)
        self.name=name.get()

    #main function
    def main(self): 
        Game.clear(self)
        Label(root,text="Welcome to the game",font=("segoe print",20)).grid(row=0,column=0)
        Label(root,text='What do you want to do?',font=("segoe print",20)).grid(row=1,column=0)
        Button(root,text="Start Game",font=("segoe print",20),command=lambda: Game.qn_func(self,1)).grid(row=2,column=0)
        Button(root,text="Exit Game",font=("segoe print",20),command=lambda: Game.exit(self)).grid(row=3,column=0)
    
    #function to check variables and display game over
    def game_over(self,x_cur):
        if x_cur[1][1]<=0 or x_cur[1][1]>=100 : #condition to check game over
            Game.clear(self)
            Label(root,text=x_cur)
            Label(root,text="GAME OVER",font=("ariel",20)).place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,anchor=CENTER)
            Button(root,text="Continue",font=("segoe print",20),command=lambda: Game.main(self)).place(relx=0.5,rely=0.6)

    #function to display question and variables
    def qn_func(self,qn_num) :
        Game.clear(self)
        #accessing the questions
        q_file = StringIO(qn)
        #reading the question, options, next qn numbers and the character name from the file
        qn_list = q_file.readlines() 
        qn = qn_list[qn_num-1].strip().split("$")[1]
        char_name = qn_list[qn_num-1].strip().split("$")[2]
        qn1 = qn_list[qn_num-1].strip().split("$")[3]
        qn2 = qn_list[qn_num-1].strip().split("$")[5]
        n_qn1 = int(qn_list[qn_num-1].strip().split("$")[4])
        n_qn2 = int(qn_list[qn_num-1].strip().split("$")[6])
        #displaying the character name and the question as a label frame widget with character name as parent
        label_frame = LabelFrame(root,text = char_name,font = ("segoe print",20))
        label = Label(label_frame,text = qn,font = ("segoe print",20))
        label_frame.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,anchor=CENTER)
        label.pack()
        q_file.close()
        #accessing variables
        v_file = StringIO(var)
        #reading values of variables from file
        v_list = v_file.readlines()
        self.r_cur[1][1] += int(v_list[qn_num-1].strip().split("$")[1])
        self.c_cur[1][1] += int(v_list[qn_num-1].strip().split("$")[2])
        self.i_cur[1][1] += int(v_list[qn_num-1].strip().split("$")[3])
        self.m_cur[1][1] += int(v_list[qn_num-1].strip().split("$")[4])
        self.p_cur[1][1] += int(v_list[qn_num-1].strip().split("$")[5])
        #running each variable through game_over to see if you are dead
        Game.game_over(self,self.r_cur)
        Game.game_over(self,self.c_cur)
        Game.game_over(self,self.i_cur)
        Game.game_over(self,self.m_cur)
        Game.game_over(self,self.p_cur)
        #defining the Doublevar variables
        s_var1 = DoubleVar()
        s_var2 = DoubleVar()
        s_var3 = DoubleVar()
        s_var4 = DoubleVar()
        s_var5 = DoubleVar()
        #setting the values in the scales
        s_var1.set(self.r_cur[1][1])
        s_var2.set(self.c_cur[1][1])
        s_var3.set(self.i_cur[1][1])
        s_var4.set(self.m_cur[1][1])
        s_var5.set(self.p_cur[1][1])
        #variables as scale widgets
        scale1 = Scale(root,from_=100,to=0,orient=VERTICAL,sliderlength=10,variable=s_var1)
        scale2 = Scale(root,from_=100,to=0,orient=VERTICAL,sliderlength=10,variable=s_var2)
        scale3 = Scale(root,from_=100,to=0,orient=VERTICAL,sliderlength=10,variable=s_var3)
        scale4 = Scale(root,from_=100,to=0,orient=VERTICAL,sliderlength=10,variable=s_var4)
        scale5 = Scale(root,from_=100,to=0,orient=VERTICAL,sliderlength=10,variable=s_var5)
        #displaying the scale widgets on the screen
        scale1.grid(row=0,column=0)
        scale2.grid(row=0,column=1)
        scale3.grid(row=0,column=2)
        scale4.grid(row=0,column=3)
        scale5.grid(row=0,column=4)
        #disabling the scales
        scale1.config(state=DISABLED)
        scale2.config(state=DISABLED)
        scale3.config(state=DISABLED)
        scale4.config(state=DISABLED)
        scale5.config(state=DISABLED)
        v_file.close()
        #displaying the buttons on the screen
        Button(root,text=qn1,command=lambda: Game.qn_func(self,n_qn1)).place(relx=0.2,rely=0.7,anchor=W,width=200,height=50)
        Button(root,text=qn2,command=lambda: Game.qn_func(self,n_qn2)).place(relx=0.8,rely=0.7,anchor=E,width=200,height=50)

game = Game()
game.start()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: "local variable 'qn' referenced before assignment" tells you what is wrong.

Comment: Please try to just include just the part that is causing the error rather than the whole code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in this particular section that you have called on 'qn' before it was even defined:

```
#function to display question and variables
    def qn_func(self,qn_num) :
        Game.clear(self)
        #accessing the questions
        q_file = StringIO(qn)
        #reading the question, options, next qn numbers and the character name from the file
        qn_list = q_file.readlines() 
        qn = qn_list[qn_num-1].strip().split("$")[1]
```

The variable needs to be assigned a value before being used. Here, you call `q_file = StringIO(qn)` before you have defined `qn = qn_list`....